# How to transfer money from a bank acc object to another bank acc object by only using the bank acc numbers of each object?

Tags: javascript, class

beginner developer here trying to understand classes more in-depth.

I have a project that first required me to create a Bank Account class like this:

```
class BankAccount{
        constructor(balance, interestRate, bankCharges)
        {
                this.balance = balance;
                this.interestRate = interestRate;
                this.bankCharges = bankCharges;
        }
        finishMonth()
        {
                this.balance = ((((this.balance * (this.interestRate/100))/12) + this.balance) - this.bankCharges);
        }
        deposit(depositedAmount)
        {
                this.balance += depositedAmount;
        }
        withdraw(withdrawal)
        {
                this.balance -= withdrawal;
        }

}
```

All three methods contained within the class are simply meant to make changes to the balance when called on an instance of the bank account class.

finishMonth() method simply charges banking fees to the Account balance and adds a certain interest to the Account balance.
deposit(amount) method simply takes in an amount and adds it to the existing account balance.
withdraw(amount) method simply takes in an amount and subtracts it from the existing account balance.

All methods were tested and can alter the balance of an instantiated Bank Account accordingly.

Part 2 of the project then required us to create a Bank (which can be associated with many Bank Accounts), the Bank has all the properties that exist in Bank Account and adds in one more property to its list, a Bank Account Number.

---

Here is the exact question for more clarity:

Create a class called Bank. A Bank contains many bank accounts. A bank associates each bank account with a 10 digit number known as a bank account number. In OOP, this is called encapsulation.

Create the following functions on your Bank class:

JavaScript:

withdraw(bankAccountNumber,amount)

deposit(bankAccountNumber,amount)

transfer(fromBankAccountNumber,toBankAccountNumber, amount)

---

The approach I took was to let Bank extend Bank Account. Here is my approach:

```
 class Bank extends BankAccount{
        constructor(balance, interestRate, bankCharges, bankAccNum)
        {
                super(balance, interestRate, bankCharges);
                this.bankAccNum = bankAccNum;
        }

        withdraw(bankAccNumber,amount)
        {
                if (bankAccNumber === this.bankAccNum)
                        super.withdraw(amount);
        }
        deposit(bankAccNumber,amount)
        {
                if (bankAccNumber === this.bankAccNum)
                        super.deposit(amount);
        }
        transfer(fromBankAccNum,toBankAccNum,amount)
        {
                if (fromBankAccNum === this.bankAccNum)
                        super.withdraw(amount);
//How do I send the amount we withdraw here to the toBankAccNum? This is where I am stuck.
                super.deposit(amount);
        }
}
```

My issue/problem lies within the **transfer(fromBankAccNum, toBankAccNum, amount)** method.

When I create two bank account instances, I can't seem to figure out how to make the one instance communicate with the other by only making use of the bank account number of each bank account.

I have figured out how to instantiate a bank account and withdraw from it, withdraw(bankAccNum, amount) first makes sure that I am withdrawing from the right bank account number before granting the withdrawal.

Now I want to be able to transfer from a bank account to another bank account just by using each bank account number. I can't figure out how to do this - how do I make the two bank account objects communicate with each other using their account numbers only?

Please note that I understand that the Bank class should not be extending the Bank Account class. I was simply experimenting and trying to figure out WHY this approach does not work. I want to understand why.

Should you feel my approach of part 2 was incorrect, kindly let me know what steps YOU would have taken to get two bank accounts to communicate by simply using their bank account numbers.

Comment: A bank isn't a bank account. It's a collection of them (among other types of accounts), as stated by your assignment. So perhaps take a step back and think about your design again, because I don't see how you can make your current `Bank` have 2 or more Bank Accounts...

Comment: Not sure this is on topic here. I think your “class” structure is wrong, a bank isn’t an extension of an account, they’re totally separate objects. A bank might have a list of accounts grouped into one or more portfolios.

Comment: If my approach does not work, how would YOU approach part 2? How do you make two separate bank account instances communicate with each other using only their bank account numbers?

Comment: Well look at it this way.. who knows about those accounts? Maybe whoever knows about them should orchestrate the transfer

Comment: Forget about programming for a minute. Which comes first; bank accounts or the bank?

Comment: Banks will come before bank accounts mate.